# Searching a word in python dictionary

Tags: python

I am tasked with building a program that will ask for an input for a word. I am to write a program to search the word in a dictionary. (I already have composed)
[My hint is: you will find the first character of the word. Get the list of words that starts with that character.
Traverse the list to find the word.]
So far I have the following code:

```
Word = input ("Search word: ")
my_file = open("input.txt",'r')
d = {}
for line in my_file:
    key = line[0]
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = [line.strip("\n")]
    else:d[key].append(line.strip("\n"))
```

I have gotten close, but I am stuck. Thank you in advance!

```
user_word=input("Search word: ")
def file_records():
    with open("input.txt",'r') as fd:
        for line in fd:
            yield line.strip()
for record in file_records():
    if record == user_word:
        print ("Word is found")
        break
for record in file_records():
    if record != user_word:
        print ("Word is not found")
        break
```

Comment: what ? you mean input.txt is a collection of all words and you are tasked to search if user input word is in input.txt ?

Comment: Yes, but our professor wants us to take the input.txt and convert it into a dictionary. From there, search if user input word is in dictionary

Comment: when you say convert file to dictionary, what format are the records in input file ? And is it a consistent pattern ?

Comment: Its just a list of words. Here is the list:

Comment: americophobia, zoophobia, bacteriophobia, pogonophobia, mastigophobia, clinophobia, apiphobia, ornithophobia, haemophobia, erythrophobia, bromidrosiphobia, gephyrophobia, ballistophobia, taphephobia, carcinophobia, ailurophobia, tocophobiapa, edophobia, Sinophobia, ecclesiophobia, nephophobia, coitophobia, cheimaphobia, chromophobia, cometophobia, cyberphobia, coprostasophobia, necrophobia, epistolophobia, demophobia/ochlophobia, hygrophobia, scotophobia, eosophobia, thanatophobia, bathophobia, mysophobia, pathophobia/nosophobia

Comment: cynophobia, oneirophobia, potophobia, pharmacophobia, koniophobia, electrophobia, claustrophobia, Anglophobia, panophobia/pantophobia, ommetaphobia, coprophobia, kakorrhaphiaphobia, kopophobia, phobophobia, pteronophobia, febriphobia

Comment: Hopefully your professor doesn't run solutions through an online plagiarism detector, or you may have just introduced a flag for your own work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
words = []
with open("input.txt",'r') as fd:
    words = [w.strip() for w in fd.readlines()]
user_word in words #will return True or False. Eg. "americophobia" in ["americophobia",...]
```

fd.readlines() reads all the lines in the file to a list and then w.strip() should strip off all leading and ending whitespaces (including newline). Else try - w.strip( \r\n\t)

`[w.strip() for w in fd.readlines()]` is called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) in python

This should work as long as the file is not too huge. If there are millions of record, you might want to consider creating a [genertor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator-expression) function to read file. Something like,

```
def file_records():
    with open("input.txt",'r') as fd:
        for line in fd:
            yield line.strip()
#and then call this function as
for record in file_records():
    if record == user_word:
        print(user_word + " is found")
        break 
else:
    print(user_word + " is not found")
```

PS: Not sure why you would need a python dictionary. Your professor would have meant English dictionary :)

Comment: Great ! just a tip for next time, you might want to format code !

Comment: Thank you again, and I had one last question. It works, but when I search a word it returns "word is found" and "word is not found"

Comment: I used the code you shared with for creating the generator

Comment: you mean it returns both ? can you paste the actual code here

Comment: posted in my original question

Comment: why do you have 2 for loops ? This alone should do

for record in file_records():
    if record == user_word:
        print ("Word is found")
        break
else:
        print ("Word is not found")

Note that else is for the for loop and not if. You can research to see what else does for a for loop :)

Comment: It still is resulting in the same result?

Comment: Updated, and still getting the same result of two outputs

Comment: I forgot to bring the else back with no indentations. Thank you thank you thank you!